# access to CalendarEvent methods

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Although I have added the Calendar API and it works for writing events from Sheets to Calendar, when I try to get an event from the calendar, the CalendarEvents methods do not work. They do not auto-complete and when typed out either error message as 'not a function' or return a null value.

Do I have to do something to initiate the CalendarEvents methods?

```
    var event=cal.getEvents(new Date (stime),new Date (etime))
   
    Logger.log (event)

        var caltitle = event.getTitle()

    Logger.log (caltitle)
...
Execution log
11:15:38 AM Notice  Execution started
11:15:39 AM Info    Fri Nov 10 10:00:00 GMT+00:00 2023
11:15:39 AM Info    Fri Nov 10 16:00:00 GMT+00:00 2023
11:15:39 AM Info    [CalendarEvent]
11:15:40 AM Error   
TypeError: event.getTitle is not a function
Calsync @ Code.gs:30
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- [getEvents(startTime, endTime)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#geteventsstarttime,-endtime) returns CalendarEvent[]. So, in your script, `event` is an array including Class CalendarEvent object. And, it seems that `getTitle()` is the method of Class CalendarEvent. But, in your script, `getTitle()` is used to an array at `var caltitle = event.getTitle()`. I think that this is the reason for your current issue.

In order to retrieve the event title from the retrieved events, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
var event = cal.getEvents(new Date(stime), new Date(etime))

Logger.log(event)

if (event.length > 0) {
  event.forEach(e => console.log(e.getTitle()));

  // or

  var eventTitle = event[0].getTitle();
  console.log(eventTitle);
} else {
  console.log("No events.");
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that `cal`, `stime` and `etime` has already been declared elsewhere. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

[getEvents(startTime, endTime)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#geteventsstarttime,-endtime)

Comment: Great, thank you. The need to reference the array was the issue.

Comment: @Chris Parsons About `Great, thank you. The need to reference the array was the issue.`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer